# Linux: How I can connect Tap and Eth0?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

[image: Question]
[Diagram of online editor link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y-Tsb5N2K2dq8_eI90eA3FXYtlb2XjNy/view?usp=sharing)

---

The raspberry pi 's system is raspbian or ubuntu.

```
ping -I 192.168.1.180 192.168.1.201 #Work [computer1 eth0 <-> rpi1 eth0]
ping -I 192.168.1.181 192.168.1.202 #Work [computer2 eth0 <-> rpi2 eth0]
ping -I 192.168.200.201 192.168.200.202 #Work [Wireless][rpi1 tap <-> rpi2 tap]

# ----------------------------------------------
ping -I 192.168.1.180 192.168.1.181 # I want connect two computers.[computer1 <->computer2]
# ----------------------------------------------

But
ping -I 192.168.1.180 192.168.200.201 #Not Work [rpi1 eth0 <-> rpi1 tap]
ping -I 192.168.1.181 192.168.200.202 #Not Work [rpi2 eth0 <-> rpi2 tap]
```

> **Wireless Connect?**
>   Now Ethernet frame is transferring with Bluetooth.
>
> Also, this is working for me.
>   ping -I 192.168.200.201 192.168.200.202 #Work [Wireless][rpi1 tap <-> rpi2 tap]

How I can connect TAP with Eth0?

---

## Main Question:

```
ping -I 192.168.1.180 192.168.200.201 #Not Work [rpi1 eth0 <-> rpi1 tap]
```

Comment: Depending on if your "Wireless Connect" (whatever that is) supports Layer 2 or not, you can either bridge (layer 2) or route (layer 3). There's plenty of tutorials and Q&A's for either.

Comment: How I can connect eth0 and tap?

Comment: You could start with editing your question and explaining what kind of "Wireless Connect" you are using, so at least we can figure out if it will work on layer 2 or not. And of course reading the manpage for `route` or `bridge` (both succeed by the newer tool `ip`, BTW) won't teach you networking basics.

Answer (score 3):

Because you want the same subnet numbering (192.168.1.0/24) on both sides, and because both interfaces seem to have a MAC layer, you can use a *bridge* to link the two interfaces. First create a "br0" bridge interface,

```
ip link add br0 type bridge
```

then set both eth0 and tap0 as bridge ports:

```
ip link set eth0 master br0
ip link set tap1 master br0
ip link set br0 up
bridge link show
```

You can use either the older `brctl` tool, or the newer `bridge` and `ip link`, makes no difference. See also [Debian docs](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections) and [interfaces file parameters](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/bridge-utils/bridge-utils-interfaces.5.en.html).

Note: The current eth0 IP configuration needs to be moved to the bridge br0 instead – any IP addresses on bridge ports will be ignored. (If it was from DHCP, then the DHCP client also moves to the bridge.)

The tap subnet 192.168.200.0 is no longer needed at all (the tap link is bridged to the main subnet), but can also be moved to br0 if you really want.

Comment: the tap can same subnet?

Comment: Can you add more explain?, I don't clear about bridge.

Comment: More specifically?

Comment: Could you check https://superuser.com/questions/1466328 ?

Answer (score 0):

sorry my reputation not reach for comment, first i think a tap connection is not the right for your wireless tunnel. i have check my pi i have eth and wlan.

The tap device inspect the traffic.
I find this Link: https://surfingthecyber.com/howto/2017/03/30/Building-RaspberryPi-Network-Tap.html

**What’s a network tap?**
A network tap is a device that is typically placed between two endpoints on a network to ‘tap into the wire’ and sniff/intercept the traffic passing by. All packets are forwarded to their intended destination so that there is no disruption of connectivity. Network taps are meant to be ‘invisible’ on the network and not modify the traffic in any way, since they are usually used to perform troubleshooting or analysis.

Comment: That's not the only thing 'tap' means, and it's not what Linux 'tap#' interfaces generally mean.